# Encoding .getJSON() API call

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, encoding, jsonp

I am working on an web app. that talks to the Last.fm API. It's working fine, except when the artist parameter contains numbers or unusual characters (e.g., "U2", "Ke$ha", etc.) How can I properly encode the parameters?

```
   for (var item in billboard) {
        track = billboard[item]['song'];
        artist = billboard[item]['artist'];
    } 
    $.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.search&artist=" + artist + "&track=" + track + "&api_key=(myapikey)&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
           try {
           var matches = data['results']['trackmatches']['track'][0]
           }
           catch(err) {
            returned = data['results']['opensearch:Query']['searchTerms']
            $('#album-display').find('ul').append(returned + "<br>")
           }
           artist = matches['artist']
           track = matches['name']
       });
    } 

var billboard = {
 "5-23-1987": {"artist": "U2", "song": "With Or Without You"},
 "10-15-1988": {"artist": "UB40", "song": "Red Red Wine"},
 "3-7-2009": {"artist": "Flo Rida Featuring Ke$ha", "song": "Right Round"},
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the URL in your request, and some of those characters aren't legal or cause issues. Change

```
$.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.search&artist=" + artist + "&track=" + track + "&api_key=(myapikey)&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
```

to

```
var query = "method=track.search&artist=" + encodeURIComponent(artist) + "&track=" + encodeURIComponent(track) + "&api_key=(myapikey)&format=json&callback=?";
$.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?" + query, function(data) {
```